# symfony - getting another field from a many-to-one to add to dbtable with orm

Tags: symfony, entity, field, symfony4, many-to-one

I have a many-to-one association in my entity and i want to grab another field to put the value in a db table instead of the title field.

my many are categories which can be set to a product. this all works fine. 
However i have an additional productcode field where i want to grab the category letter instead of title.

my category entity

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**

 * @ORM\Entity()

 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()

 */

class Category

{

    /**

     * @ORM\Id()

     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()

     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")

     */

    private $id;

    /**

     * @var string

     *

     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")

     */

    private $title;


    /**

     * @var string

     *

     * @ORM\Column(name="categoryletter", type="string")

     */

    private $categoryletter;

    public function getId(): ?int

    {

        return $this->id;

    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string

    {

        return $this->title;

    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self

    {

        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;

    }

    public function getCategoryletter(): ?string

    {

        return $this->categoryletter;

    }

    public function setCategoryletter(string $categoryletter): self

    {

        $this->categoryletter = $categoryletter;

        return $this;

    }

    /**

     * @return string

     */

     public function __toString()

     {
         return $this->title;

     }


}
```

in my product.php entity i have the following code

```
    /**
     * @var Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $category;
```

where i have an additional field to set a partical productcode based on category etc. but i don't want the category title but the associated categoryletter

```
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setProductcode() 
    {

  {
     $part = $this->category;   

    $this->productcode = $part;

    }
```

I don't know how to grab another field of the category entity. If i change function __toString to categoryletter instead of title i do get the letter, but i want to stick with the title field just for general purpose.How do i get the categoryletter field? or is this not possible in a direct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the orm is properly made between the two entities you can just use the getter :

```
     /**
     * set productCode
     *
     * @return Product
     */
public function setProductcode() 
   {
      $category = $this->category;   
      $this->productcode = $category->getCategoryletter();

      return $this;

     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that did the trick. I was trying to get the field, but was stuck. btw, why you don't use      `* @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */` but    ` *
     * @return Product
     */`  ? just curious :)

Comment: Usually, setters return the entity, but they could still return something else if you want them to